# Remove HH:mm:sec for From & To Date search

Tags: magento-1.8

We are fetching orders from magento database & displaying in custom page :  **www.1234.com/php/site6/orders.php** 
we are Displaying From & To Date for filtering orders based on those dates.

here **00:0:00 & 23:59:59** is displaying along with from & To date. [ hours : min : sec]

[image]

but i want to hide : **00:00:00 & 23:59:59** , so i removed those text from code, after that Filtering based on Dates not working. is there any issue with Date format ?

[image]

```
if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
    {
    $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . " 00:0:00";
    }
  else
    {
    $orderFromDate = '';
    }

if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
    {
    $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . " 23:59:59";
    }
  else
    {
    $orderToDate = '';
    }

function getDesignerCollection()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['post_at']) && $_POST['post_at'] != '')
        {
        $orderFromDate = $_POST['post_at'] . "00:0:00 ";
        }
      else
        {
        $orderFromDate = '';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['post_at_to_date']) && $_POST['post_at_to_date'] != '')
        {
        $orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . "23:59:59 ";
        }
      else
        {
        $orderToDate = '';
        }

        if ($orderFromDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'gteq' => $orderFromDate
        ));
        if ($orderToDate != '') $order->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array(
            'lteq' => $orderToDate
        ));

        foreach($order as $orderData)
        {
        $oDate = new DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
        $sDate = $oDate->format("Y-m-d");
        }

    }
```

**script**

```
jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({
showOn: "button",
buttonText: "Date Picker",
buttonImageOnly: true,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'  
});
$(function() {
$("#post_at").datepicker();
$("#post_at_to_date").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Please check Myupdated answer

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala sorry, not working for me. looks like i am doing something wrong, when you get free time please check code of the file here : http://pastebin.com/vshnbV9z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use default PHP date function for your requirement

```
$date = date("d M Y", strtotime($yourdate));
```

for your date format you can visit this url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Ok so when you filter your value then just change your post value by this

```
$newPostDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($postToDate));
```

Or try this

```
$newPostStartDate = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime($postStartDate));

$newPostEndDate = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($postEndDate));
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please update the answer with some more code as for my requirement......

Comment: @BabyinMagento please check my updated code

Comment: sorry, it did't worked for me , seems i am doing something wrong,  if you update an answer with complete code that will be really helpfull.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I think the problem lies with you is when you select date `2016-12-1` for both place my date format always convert it to `2016-12-1 00:00:00` so you can put validation that start date and end date should not be the same

Comment: sorry ,i can't put validation as like that because there may be 10 orders in  in same day, if sellers/designers want to see all orders in day that will not be possible at that time.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento try to add extra space in this code as sample before hh::mm::ss `$orderToDate = $_POST['post_at_to_date'] . " 23:59:59 ";`

Comment: Tried that, no change in result except space b/w date & time as `2016-12-01              23:59:59

Answer (score 2):

You are adding this at the end of the date `"00:0:00 "`. As you can see there is only one zero for minutes and a space at the end.
You should append this `"00:00:00"`.

Same goes for `"23:59:59 "`. It should be `"23:59:59"` without the space after 59.

Comment: sorry, i tried as you mentioned. but it did't worked for me, may be somewhere else i am missing,  this is updated code related to Date : http://pastebin.com/GPy9H5YZ & this is complete file code : http://pastebin.com/uLFZ1dK7 , please check when you get free time....

Answer (score 1):

Credits : **Murtuza Zabuawala**

```
 $newPostStartDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['post_at']));
 $newPostEndDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['post_at_to_date']));
```

Comment: And What you have do for end date ?

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala updated answer.....

Comment: ok got it    .....

Comment: Ok No worrys....

Comment: I will update My answers as marius suggested So other user who has same problem get benefits